# Finite simple subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, linear-groups

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer. Is it true that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of finite nonabelian simple subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$?

I'm especially interested in the answers which not use sophisticated facts and theorems. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this follows from the Jordan-Schur theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Schur_theorem

Comment: And by the way the older form due to Jordan is enough here: every subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbf{C})$ has an abelian subgroup of index $\le C_d$. See https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/27/254a-notes-0-hilberts-fifth-problem-and-related-topics/ for an elegant proof.